# I need help understanding some pythonic "dictify" / "jsonify" code fragments

Tags: python, dictionary, json

I need help understanding this python jsonify/dictify code so I can replicate it:

```
TYPES = {}

# auto-register all already defined subclasses of CustomObject to the types map
# so they will become seriazible/deseriazible
for N,T in locals().items():
    if isinstance(T, type) and issubclass(T, CustomObject):
        TYPES[N] = T


def CustomTypeDecoder(dct):
    type_name = dct.get('type')
    if type_name:
        cls = TYPES.get(type_name)
        if cls:
            return cls(**dct)
    return dct

def loads(s):
    return json.loads(s, object_hook=CustomTypeDecoder) 


class CustomTypeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, tuple(TYPES.values())):
            res = dict(type=obj.__class__.__name__)
            res.update(obj.to_dict())
            return res
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def dumps(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls=CustomTypeEncoder)
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Be specific.

Comment: Everything ... I get that it is registering a type of JSON but that's it.

Comment: "Everything" is not specific.  Please share what your goal is.  Are you trying to modify it?  Extend it?  Debug it?  Use it?  What problem do you have?  What are you failing to do?

Comment: I don't understand anything other then the high-level purpose of the code. It's in my code base and I need to use it to extend the encoding/decoding of JSON classes.

Comment: @user407601: Please **update** your question to describe specifically what you mean by "extend the encoding/decoding of JSON classes".  In detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that does the hard work is in the class itself. Lines 15 and 27 use the class functionality to convert the class from and to dicts, which are JSON-serializable; the rest is all administrivia code.